# MQSeries Docker image: queue manager without authentication

Tags: docker, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

How can I make the queue manager (which exists by default in the docker image) accept any connection without authentication?

I went through all the options in the web console (:9443/ibmmq/console/) and tried anything that I thought might have the effect I wanted, but couldn't find it.

TIA & BR,
Christian

Edit: here's the code I'm using to connect

```
JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
//cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
//cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
//cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

// Create JMS objects
context = cf.createContext();
```

----------edit------------

Error log after

- removing "connection authentication" for the QM
- setting the channel auth. record (under extended) to "As Queue Manager"

```
    AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for '[my OS user]'. 
EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID '[my OS user]' failed with CompCode 2 and
Reason 2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
```

Comment: The first error you posted about password was checked because of chlauth rule I think you figured out but to check which CHLAUTH rule in the future you can run this type of command `DIS CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) TYPE(ALL) MATCH(RUNCHECK) CLNTUSER([my os username]) ADDRESS(172.18.0.1)`.

Comment: For the most recent `AMQ9557E` error this means the your os user is not defined where the queue manager is running.  You can define that user there and apply OAM to allow it to connect and PUT/GET from the queue, or if you have another user already defined you can set the `MCAUSER` attribute of the channel to that already defined user and if required apply OAM rules to allow it to connect and put/get from the queue.

Comment: I would not recommend you use the `mqm` user or a user in the `mqm` group, even if this is for test purposes, when you get to prod you will be thankful you figured out the security in test when you had time to, not in prod when you are against a deadline, or worst an auditor.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc, adding the user "app" (the default user for the docker image, it seems) in the channel properties under "MCA" did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to disable the MQ Connection Authentication feature so that userid & passwords are not authenticated then you can do this by executing the following MQSC commands in runmqsc against the Queue Manager.

`ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
REFRESH SECURITY(*) TYPE(CONAUTH)`

Alternatively in the MQ web Console:

1. Select your queue manager in the Queue Manager widget
2. Click properties
3. Go to the Extended section and scroll down
4. Set the "Connection Authentication" attribute to a blank value
5. Click save adn then close
6. Select your queue manager in the Queue Manager widgit
7. Click the `...` and select Refresh security from the drop down
8. "Select connection authentication"
9. Add widget: "Channel authentication records"
10. In this widget, select the entry for your channel, click properties under "Extended" set client connections to "As Queue Manager"

If required:

Select your QM in the "Queue Manager" widget, open properties (...), "refresh security...", "Connection authentication". 
Make sure the default user name (in the standard docker installation, that's "app") is set in the channel properties under MCA (as sugg. by @JoshMc)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I tried that, but it seems I need to change the way I am connecting then, too. With the suggested changes, I am now getting the following log output:

The client application user ID and password cannot be checked by the queue manager. 

I'll add the code I'm using in the post.

Comment: Provide output of command `DIS CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Run following mqsc commands to disable channel authentication in IBM MQ server:

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```